# why is absolute element width limited by inline-block parent

Tags: css

I have the [following setup](http://plnkr.co/edit/FJyyGo3e2ySuUDlTH751?p=preview):

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background: green;
}

a {
   width: 25px;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    some
    <div>
      <a href="">1</a>
      <a href="">2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My question is why the `div` that contains `a` elements collapses on parent div width? I'd expect `a` elements to stay in one line but they wrapped. Is it expected behavior? How can I work around it?

Comment: Collapses cause the parent is `inline-block` (not `block`), and has not a defined `top, bottom, left, right` position (as being absolute)

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out that already. Why is it so? Any workaround? I don't want to change parent div to block element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd expect a elements to stay in one line but they wrapped. Is it expected behavior?

Yes. they're floated left, but the parent is absolute positioned so constrained from the document floats. Has no width set so the inner elements align to the available space (0) even being left-floated.

`a` elements are `inline` elements by default.
First of all you'll have to remove `float` from your `anchors`, set them rather to be `inline-block`. Still they're vertically positioned, to fix that set `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent.

```css
div{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

div div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background: green;
    white-space: nowrap; /* needed! for inner inline elements */
}

a {
   width: 25px;
   display:inline-block; /* needed just for the 25px width! (otherw. remove) */
}
```

```html
<div>
    some
    <div>
      <a href="">1</a>
      <a href="">2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: While true, it doesn't explain *Why*. Besides, the computed `display` of floated `a` elements would be `inline-block`.

Comment: @HashemQolami than *you* can use `float-left` if it computes as being `display:inline-block` ;) http://jsfiddle.net/2x0xd6ej/

Comment: @HashemQolami - No, the computed display of floated `a` elements, (assuming that no other explicit display value is being set) is `block`, not `inline-block`. See the table at [9.7 Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

Comment: I don't need to use either :) However, I should note - respectively - that it still doesn't explain the reason of the issue technically. `[...] the parent is absolute positioned so constrained from the document floats.` It's not about the floated elements at all. This happens because the the [width of the absolutely positioned non-replaced element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) is *shrink-to-fit* in this case.

Comment: @HashemQolami well correct *shrink-to-fit* is nice, I've used the `elements align to the available space (0)`. Thanks